# Night light and Redshift don't work

Tags: gnome, 18.04, screen, colors, temperature

I installed Ubuntu on a disk partition just two days ago and everything work like a charm. The only problem I'm having is with the screen temperature color. In Windows I use *f.lux* and I set the color temperature as red as possible (3500K) all-day-long. I want to do the same in Ubuntu but I faced many issues:

- **f.lux** doesn't change the color at all
- **Redshift** changes the temperature for a couple of seconds, then it suddenly goes back to the normal color
- **GNOME Night Light** has the same problem of Redshift: the change is not permanent although I set the color temperature to be 3500K from 5AM to 3AM

Is anyone having the same problem? How can I fix it?

---

System info:

- Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
- GNOME 3.28.2
- External monitor HP 24" 60,00 Hz

Comment: f.lux is buggy and won't work on most 18.04 installation. Other 2 should've worked.

Comment: go to:
[https://www.computercorrect.com/2018/operating-systems/linux/ubuntu/ubuntu-night-light-tips-tweaks/](https://www.computercorrect.com/2018/operating-systems/linux/ubuntu/ubuntu-night-light-tips-tweaks/)
there follow the instructions and resetting the settings a bit.
Started working for me after i switched it off from the tool, changed the timing settings to default and then turned it on

Comment: If you want red all day long you don't have to use any of those programs. Just use `xrandr` at boot time with appropriate gamma settings.

Answer (score 5):

I found that for Night Light I have to set it to manual mode and set the start time to some time before the current time and the end time sometime before the end time.

I was perplexed for a while because I assumed that, like all other widgets in Ubuntu, setting the switch to on (green) would just turn Night Light on.

Answer (score 3):

Try un-installing redshift, then use a night light.

I was also having some issues with redshift, couldn't get it to work.  So then I tried [night light](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/display-night-light.html.en) - the colour temperature would flash on for a second and then off again...periodically.

I think there might have been a conflict with redshift, because after I uninstalled it from the command line with

```
sudo apt-get remove redshift
```

then the colour temperature on night light seemed to work as expected.

Comment: Uninstalling redshift fixed Gnome's Night Light for me and I'm running Gnome on Arch Linux.