# Night Light only flashes my screen

Tags: 18.10

I'm fairly new to Ubuntu and the Linux world, but whenever I turn on the Night Light feature on my laptop running Ubuntu 18.10, my screen completely tint-flashes  with orange then goes back to normal as if I never turned on Night Light. Yet Ubuntu still says it's on.

It turns out that my issue was being caused by the extension I will as soon as I using.

Comment: If you have [found the cause](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1090116/night-light-only-flashes-my-screen/1090120#comment1793773_1090120), please post it with a solution/workaround as an answer below by clicking the "answer your question" button below to help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Possible Duplicate of [night-light-and-redshift-dont-work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065505/night-light-and-redshift-dont-work)

Go to: https://www.computercorrect.com/2018/operating-systems/linux/ubuntu/ubuntu-night-light-tips-tweaks/

To find out how to reset and tweak night light settings.

**Synopsis:**
The easiest way to control your night light settings is **dconf editor**, which is a low level system and settings manager.

1. First run `sudo apt-get upgrade` from your terminal.
2. Then run `sudo apt-get install dconf-editor -y`
3. You will now find an app on your desktop which looks like a magnifying glass with a tick in it. This is dconf, open it.
4. In the bar at the top you will see a file path.
5. Change this to `org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/color/night-light-temperature` or alternatively click the search icon and search for *"night light"*.
6. You will see at the bottom you can set a custom value. Use this to set the night light to a strength you prefer.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out that it was my desktop extension, Extend Panel Menu to blame for my problems, thank you for the help though