# Night light turn off automatically after few seconds

Tags: night-light

In Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS kernel version 5.16.3-051603-generic. When I turn on night light it gets disabled automatically after few seconds.

Like this:
[Error video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r_a9YOO1VQ4)

What is the cause of problem? Is there anything I can do?

Any help will be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer instead of editing the question.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for pointing out I'm new here.

Answer (score 2):

I got it. Thanks to this answer - [Night light and Redshift don't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065505/night-light-and-redshift-dont-work).

I first uninstalled redshift with the command

`sudo apt-get remove redshift` then

Automatic night light does not seems to work. So, I changed to manual timings and it worked now.

Answer (score 2):

The 'Sunrise to Sunset' option was causing this for me.

In a similar vein to @elgeschickto's answer, one solution is to go to Settings -> Displays -> Night Light and change the schedule to 'Manual Schedule' and then set appropriate times.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason may be that location services is turned off.

Apparently, in that case, the system gets the time for sunrise and sunset wrong.

I just experienced this: it was well after sunset, I toggled Night Light on. Nothing happened. Schedule was set to "Sunset to Sunrise", as desired. Then I moved the Color Temperature slider and the screen's color immediately changed. But after a few seconds, it just changed back.

I didn't have Redshift installed in the first place.

But when I enabled Location Services (Settings → Privacy → Location Services) the Night Light kicked in almost immediately. And stayed on.

So, this seems to be another possible cause for the symptom described in the original post.